# Delphi: Sierpinski triangle: procedure not running itself completely

Tags: delphi

I don't understand why this code draws this:

[image]
Only the bottom-left triangles seem to draw, however the inner-triangles appear only in the first depth of the top- and bottom-right triangle. I want the procedure to be recursive, but it is somehow cause of my shitty programming skills not recursive. I really want an understanding of what I am doing wrong.

```
implementation

{$R *.dfm}

var
  count : integer = 0;

procedure DrawTriangle(aCanvas: TCanvas;x,y,size : extended;n : integer);
var
  h : extended;
  w : extended;
  i : integer;
  x1,x2,x3,y1,y2,y3 : extended;
begin
    w := size;
    h := size;
    x1 := x;
    y1 := y;
    //ShowMessage(FloatToStr(w)+' '+FloatToStr(h));
  if aCanvas<>nil then
  try
    //1st - left
    aCanvas.MoveTo(Round(x1),Round(y1));
    aCanvas.LineTo(Round(x1+w*2),Round(y1));
    aCanvas.LineTo(Round(x1+w),Round(y1-h));
    aCanvas.LineTo(Round(x1),Round(y1));
    //2nd - right
    x2 := x1+w*2;
    y2 := y1;
    aCanvas.MoveTo(Round(x2),Round(y2));
    aCanvas.LineTo(Round(x2+w*2),Round(y2));
    aCanvas.LineTo(Round(x2+w),Round(y2-h));
    aCanvas.LineTo(Round(x2),Round(y2));
    //3rd - top
    x3 := x2-w;
    y3 := y2-h;
    aCanvas.MoveTo(Round(x3),Round(y3));
    aCanvas.LineTo(Round(x3+w*2),Round(y3));
    aCanvas.LineTo(Round(x3+w),Round(y3-h));
    aCanvas.LineTo(Round(x3),Round(y3));

    //Run itself
    inc(count);
    if count < n then
    begin
      DrawTriangle(aCanvas,x1,y1,size/2,n);
      DrawTriangle(aCanvas,x2,y2,size/2,n);
      DrawTriangle(aCanvas,x3,y3,size/2,n);
    end;
  except
    on e: exception do raise e;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  size : extended;
  i : integer;
  x,y : extended;
begin
  size := 100;
  x := 100;
  y := 400;
  DrawTriangle(Image1.Canvas,x,y,size,10);
end;
end.
```

Comment: The count variable is causing your problems. First call will increase the count and recurse first line, which will do the same, etc until count is > n. Then the second and third calls will be executed but not recursed.

Comment: It serves no purpose to use the non standard 80 bit Intel x87 type Extended. Use Double.

Comment: @David - It's interesting that you categorise Extended as "non-standard" at the same time as referencing the standard it represents.  ;)  Delphi uses Extended for many internal floating point ops (or used to), converting to/from declared types as required, so I don't see why using it in your own code should be considered distasteful.  Quite the opposite in fact.  Perhaps you were getting confused with "Real" ?  If not, I'd be curious as to your reasons for suggesting this change.  (NB. I typically use Double myself but wonder if there is some consideration here that I'm not aware of).

Comment: @Deltics As you know I write a performance critical floating point finite element program, so have quite a bit of experience here. I do know what `Real` is and am confused about nothing here. 80 bit extended is not defined by the IEEE754 standard. The standard suggests an extended format that can be used for intermediate temps, as a means to improve accuracy. However, its usefulness is moot. x64 FPU is SSE which does not have 80 bit type. Using 80 bit types for storage (as opposed to temps) is very slow due to poor alignment.

Comment: @David, you seem to think I keep a copy of your CV in my head.  I don't.  First, a *different* standard (than one not identified) is not the same as **non**-standard.  Second, without qualification the advice was just puzzling since it had no apparent relevance to the question.  At the very least it should have been "consider using Double" with a some supporting info or a link (you might have provided this:  http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-floats.html), rather than an absolute and unqualified dictat/decree.  imho.

Comment: @Deltics Well we disagree here. If we can't agree what the fp standard is then there's no ground for meaningful discourse.

Comment: @David, IEEE754 is **a** standard.  80-bit x87 is also **a** standard.  I'm not trying to agree which of those is most deserving of the definite pronoun.  It may be relevant to your project work and an interesting discussion in itself, but is wholly irrelevant to this question.  In any event, your unqualified comment has now been qualified, which was what I was hoping for.  So all good.  :)

Comment: @Deltics I disagree over what x87 is. It's not a standard. Which standards body deals with its standardisation? It is a specific fp micro processor architecture. Using single or double allows you to adhere to the IEEE754 standard and so be portable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your attempt to limit the depth of recursion contains an error.

You draw each of the 3 inner triangles and increment **count**, and then call **DrawTriangle** again to draw the triangles within those triangles.  Each call increments **count** *again*, meaning that count does not reflect the depth of recursion but simply how many times **DrawTriangle** has been called.  As a result of specifying a limit of 10, you will find that in your results, 10 sets of triangles have been drawn.

Instead of incrementing **count** to track recursion depth you should *decrement* **n** for each call until **n = 0**.

To make this intention clearer you can use a nested procedure where the outer call accepts the maximum number of levels of recursion specified with the inner, nested procedure doing the actual recursion indicating the number of levels remaining and decrementing this number for the recursive calls themselves:

```
procedure DrawTriangle(aCanvas: TCanvas;x,y,size : extended; maxLevels: integer);

  procedure Draw(x,y,size: extended; levelsLeft: integer);
  var
    h : extended;
    w : extended;
    i : integer;
    x1,x2,x3,y1,y2,y3 : extended;
  begin
    w := size;
    h := size;
    x1 := x;
    y1 := y;

    //1st - left
    aCanvas.MoveTo(Round(x1),Round(y1));
    aCanvas.LineTo(Round(x1+w*2),Round(y1));
    aCanvas.LineTo(Round(x1+w),Round(y1-h));
    aCanvas.LineTo(Round(x1),Round(y1));

    //2nd - right
    x2 := x1+w*2;
    y2 := y1;
    aCanvas.MoveTo(Round(x2),Round(y2));
    aCanvas.LineTo(Round(x2+w*2),Round(y2));
    aCanvas.LineTo(Round(x2+w),Round(y2-h));
    aCanvas.LineTo(Round(x2),Round(y2));

    //3rd - top
    x3 := x2-w;
    y3 := y2-h;
    aCanvas.MoveTo(Round(x3),Round(y3));
    aCanvas.LineTo(Round(x3+w*2),Round(y3));
    aCanvas.LineTo(Round(x3+w),Round(y3-h));
    aCanvas.LineTo(Round(x3),Round(y3));

    //Run itself
    if (levelsLeft > 0) then
    begin
      Draw(x1, y1, size/2, levelsLeft - 1);
      Draw(x2, y2, size/2, levelsLeft - 1);
      Draw(x3, y3, size/2, levelsLeft - 1);
    end;
  end;

begin
  if Assigned(aCanvas) then
    Draw(x, y, size, maxLevels);
end;
```

This also allows pre-conditions to be tested in a clearer fashion, in this case limited currently to ensuring that a canvas has been specified, but could also involve normalising or validating other parameters as might be required, before initiating the recursive call.

Since the original parameters remain in scope for the nested procedure it also means that you can limit the parameters in the calls to the recursive procedure to only those which actually change on each call.  (I have updated the code in my answer to incorporate this).

Incidentally, a `try..except` that simply raises any caught exceptions is exactly equivalent to having no `try..except` block at all so I removed it from this implementation.

Also you might wish to consider adding an additional condition to halt recursion if the value of **size** reaches a certain minima (where the inner triangles are indistinct, e.g. **size < 2**).

Comment: Thank you! You made me understand. :) I feel a bit silly now.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that you draw the first triangle, then you call `DrawTriangle` to draw the bottom-left part, which does that, and then calls `DrawTriangle` to draw the new bottom-left part, and so on, until `count` has reached `n`. Then we return one procedure at a time to the original procedure, and in each step we draw the remaining two triangles only once.

The following logic works as intended. (Remove the global `count` variable.)

```
procedure DrawTriangle(aCanvas: TCanvas; x, y, size: extended; n: integer);
var
  h: extended;
  w: extended;
  x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3: extended;
begin
  w := size;
  h := size;
  x1 := x;
  y1 := y;

  //1st - left
  aCanvas.MoveTo(Round(x1), Round(y1));
  aCanvas.LineTo(Round(x1+w*2), Round(y1));
  aCanvas.LineTo(Round(x1+w), Round(y1-h));
  aCanvas.LineTo(Round(x1), Round(y1));
  //2nd - right
  x2 := x1+w*2;
  y2 := y1;
  aCanvas.MoveTo(Round(x2), Round(y2));
  aCanvas.LineTo(Round(x2+w*2), Round(y2));
  aCanvas.LineTo(Round(x2+w), Round(y2-h));
  aCanvas.LineTo(Round(x2), Round(y2));
  //3rd - top
  x3 := x2-w;
  y3 := y2-h;
  aCanvas.MoveTo(Round(x3), Round(y3));
  aCanvas.LineTo(Round(x3+w*2), Round(y3));
  aCanvas.LineTo(Round(x3+w), Round(y3-h));
  aCanvas.LineTo(Round(x3), Round(y3));

  //Run itself
  if n > 0 then
  begin
    DrawTriangle(aCanvas, x1, y1, size/2, n-1);
    DrawTriangle(aCanvas, x2, y2, size/2, n-1);
    DrawTriangle(aCanvas, x3, y3, size/2, n-1);
  end;
end;
```

I leave it as an exercise to figure out *why* it works.

Also notice I removed the completely unnecessary `try..except` block.

Finally, you can write the code much more efficiently, as [demonstrated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26748087/282848) by Sir Rufo.

Answer (score 4):

Just as an addition to the given answers, here is a DRY version:

```
procedure DrawTriangleDRY( aCanvas: TCanvas; CenterX, CenterY, Width, Height: extended; n: integer );
begin
  aCanvas.MoveTo( Round( CenterX ), Round( CenterY - Height / 2 ) ); // top
  aCanvas.LineTo( Round( CenterX + Width / 2 ), Round( CenterY + Height / 2 ) ); // bottom right
  aCanvas.LineTo( Round( CenterX - Width / 2 ), Round( CenterY + Height / 2 ) ); // bottom left
  aCanvas.LineTo( Round( CenterX ), Round( CenterY - Height / 2 ) ); // top

  // draw childs
  if n > 0
  then
    begin
      // top
      DrawTriangleDRY( aCanvas, CenterX, CenterY - Height / 4, Width / 2, Height / 2, n - 1 );
      // left
      DrawTriangleDRY( aCanvas, CenterX - Width / 4, CenterY + Height / 4, Width / 2, Height / 2, n - 1 );
      // right
      DrawTriangleDRY( aCanvas, CenterX + Width / 4, CenterY + Height / 4, Width / 2, Height / 2, n - 1 );
    end;
end;
```

---

**Update**

I just realized, that this can be optimized to only draw the last childs

```
procedure DrawTriangleDRY( aCanvas: TCanvas; CenterX, CenterY, Width, Height: extended; n: integer );
begin
  // draw childs
  if n > 0
  then
    begin
      DrawTriangleDRY( aCanvas, CenterX, CenterY - Height / 4, Width / 2, Height / 2, n - 1 ); // top
      DrawTriangleDRY( aCanvas, CenterX - Width / 4, CenterY + Height / 4, Width / 2, Height / 2, n - 1 ); // left
      DrawTriangleDRY( aCanvas, CenterX + Width / 4, CenterY + Height / 4, Width / 2, Height / 2, n - 1 ); // right
    end
  else
    begin
      aCanvas.MoveTo( Round( CenterX ), Round( CenterY - Height / 2 ) ); // top
      aCanvas.LineTo( Round( CenterX + Width / 2 ), Round( CenterY + Height / 2 ) ); // bottom right
      aCanvas.LineTo( Round( CenterX - Width / 2 ), Round( CenterY + Height / 2 ) ); // bottom left
      aCanvas.LineTo( Round( CenterX ), Round( CenterY - Height / 2 ) ); // top
    end
end;
```

Comment: Indeed, it is enough to draw a single triangle.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if I understand your question correctly, and I don't know the `Sierpinski` algorithm. However to represent a filled triangle, so that you can use the function created to represent filled polygons (example: a quadrilateral), since they can always be divided into triangles, it is necessary to be able to exclude the representation of a side, otherwise, it would happen that one side of a triangle is overwritten by the side of the adjacent triangle (problems in displaying transparent polygons).
This, which I propose to you, is the `Delphi` implementation of my algorithm for the representation of any type of  triangles; unfortunately, if you want to use the `Sierpinski` algorithm, my answer may not be pertinent. I advise you to try it, because it is very fast, although quite complex, and efficient. it is my variant of the `Bresenham` algorithm. The implementation of the routine representing a horizontal segment, I remaind it to you (just replace the call to `Put`(Shadow)`HorizLine ()`, for the representation of the horizontal segment, with the `Line ()` instruction).

Here is it the types of data:

```
Const R_OBP_Al=16; {16 Byte alignment; it must always be 2^N}
      DimOBP_H=16; {16 Byte of OBP HEADER; it must always be >=4}

Type TShadowTable=Array[0..255] Of Byte; {Array for shadows}

     T_Shadow_Table_Ptr=^TShadowTable; {Pointer to an array for shadows}

     T_Coord_XY=Record {Coordinates of a point}
      X
      Y :SmallInt;
     End;

     T_Pos_Coord_XY=Record {Coordinates of the clipping-region}
      X,
      Y :Word;
     End;

     T_Dim_XY=Record {Dimensions of the clipping-region}
      DimX,
      DimY :Word;
     End;

     T_Clipp_Rect=Record {Clipping-region's type}
      XY {Coordinates of the clipping-region} :T_Pos_Coord_XY;
      Dim_XY {Dimensions of the clipping-region} :T_Dim_XY;
     End;

     T_Clipp_Rect_Ptr=^T_Clipp_Rect; {Pointer to clipping-region's type}

     T_Rect=Record {Rectangle type}
      XY {Coordinates of the rectangle} :T_Coord_XY;
      Dim_XY {Dimensions of the rectangle} :T_Dim_XY;
     End;

     T_Rect_Ptr=^T_Rect; {Tipo PUNTATORE a RECORD RETTANGOLO}
```

Here it is the body of the triangle routine:

```
Procedure Triangle_Wind(X1,Y1,X2,Y2,X3,Y3,
                        FillColor,BrdColAB,BrdColBC,BrdColCA:SmallInt;
                        ShadowTable:T_Shadow_Table_Ptr;
                        OBPVBuff:Pointer;
                        Clipp:T_Clipp_Rect_Ptr);

(* AVVERTENZA: Nonostante gli irrilevanti problemi
               nella visualizzazione del bordo, solido o trasparente,
               del triangolo, tuttora esistenti, dato che questa funzione
               è molto complessa, VIETATO APPORTARE MODIFICHE:
               FUNZIONE OTTIMIZZATA (HA RICHIESTO 60 ORE DI TEMPO,
               tra studio, sviluppo di un valido ALGORITMO, implementazione,
               beta-testing, realizzazione del programma
               di debugging ("TstQd.DPR") e debugging) ! *)

Var A,B,C, (* Identificatori vertici triangoli per ordinamento dei colori *)

    C1,C2,C3, (* VAR. temp.: contengono i colori BrdColAB, BrdColBC, BrdColCA *)

    XT, (* X1-XT è il SEGMENTO orizzontale da disegnare *)

    OY2, (* Valore iniziale della coordinata Y del 2° vertice del triangolo *)

    B1L,B1H, (* Coordinata X 1° e ultimo PUNTO del 1° bordo (Segm. orizz.) *)
    B2L,B2H, (* Coordinata X 1° e ultimo PUNTO del 2° bordo (Segm. orizz.) *)

    D0, (* Dimensione 1° bordo (Segm. orizz.) *)
    D1, (* Dimensione parte centrale Segm. orizz. *)
    D2, (* Dimensione 2° bordo (Segm. orizz.) *)

    Tmp, (* Variabile temporanea x scambio di 2 variabili *)

    Col1, (* Colore 1° bordo Segm. orizz. *)
    Col2, (* Colore 2° bordo Segm. orizz. *)

    CntX1, (* Contat. per coord. X 1° PUNTO Segm. orizz. (Bresenham) *)
    IncX1, (* Increm. contat. per coord. X 1° PUNTO Segm. OR. (Bresenham) *)
    CntY1, (* Contat. per coord. Y 1° PUNTO Segm. orizz. (Bresenham) *)
    Lim1, (* Limite per contat. coord. X e Y 1° PUNTO Segm. OR. (Bresenham) *)
    DirX1, (* Increm. coord. X 1° PUNTO Segm. orizz. *)
    IncY1, (* Increm. contat. per coord. Y 1° PUNTO Segm. OR. (Bresenham) *)
    FX1, (* Valore iniziale coord. X1 Segm. orizz. X1-XT *)

    CntXT, (* Contat. per coord. X 2° PUNTO Segm. orizz. (Bresenham) *)
    IncXT, (* Increm. contat. per coord. X 2° PUNTO Segm. OR. (Bresenham) *)
    CntYT, (* Contat. per coord. Y 2° PUNTO Segm. orizz. (Bresenham) *)
    LimT, (* Limite per contat. coord. X e Y 2° PUNTO Segm. OR. (Bresenham) *)
    DirXT, (* Increm. coord. X 2° PUNTO Segm. orizz. *)
    IncYT, (* Increm. contat. per coord. Y 2° PUNTO Segm. OR. (Bresenham) *)
    FXT (* Valore iniziale coord. XT Segm. orizz. X1-XT *):SmallInt;

    Segm (* RECORD per la rappresentazione di un Segm. orizz. *):T_Rect;
    F1, (* 1° condizione iniziale (eccezione), rappresentaz. triang. *)
    F24, (* 2° condizione iniziale (eccezione), rappresentaz. triang. *)
    Overflow, (* FALSE: Sta calc. il Segm. orizz.; TRUE: Ha finito *)
    Internal, (* Variabile temp. che salva il valore iniziale di OVERFLOW *)
    Finished (* FALSE: 2° semi-triang.; TRUE: 1° semi-triang. *) :Boolean;

Begin

 A:=0;
 B:=1;
 C:=2;

 (* Ordina i vertici IN base alla coordinata Y *)

 If Y1>Y2 Then
  Begin
   Tmp:=X1;
   X1:=X2;
   X2:=Tmp;
   Tmp:=Y1;
   Y1:=Y2;
   Y2:=Tmp;
   Tmp:=A;
   A:=B;
   B:=Tmp;
  End;

 If Y2>Y3 Then
  Begin
   Tmp:=X2;
   X2:=X3;
   X3:=Tmp;
   Tmp:=Y2;
   Y2:=Y3;
   Y3:=Tmp;
   Tmp:=B;
   B:=C;
   C:=Tmp;
  End;

 If Y1>Y2 Then
  Begin
   Tmp:=X1;
   X1:=X2;
   X2:=Tmp;
   Tmp:=Y1;
   Y1:=Y2;
   Y2:=Tmp;
   Tmp:=A;
   A:=B;
   B:=Tmp;
  End;

 (* Calcola il colore effettivo dei lati A-B, B-C e C-A del triangolo *)

 C1:=BrdColAB;
 C2:=BrdColBC;
 C3:=BrdColCA;

 Case 27*A+9*B+C Of
   19:Begin
       BrdColAB:=C3;
       BrdColCA:=C1;
      End;
   29:Begin
       BrdColBC:=C3;
       BrdColCA:=C2;
      End;
   45:Begin
       BrdColAB:=C2;
       BrdColBC:=C3;
       BrdColCA:=C1;
      End;
   55:Begin
       BrdColAB:=C3;
       BrdColBC:=C1;
       BrdColCA:=C2;
      End;
   63:Begin
       BrdColAB:=C2;
       BrdColBC:=C1;
      End;
 End;

 (* Calc. gli Incr. e i limiti, inizial. i cont. per il lato A-C (Bresenham) *)

 DirXT:=-1;
 IncXT:=X1-X3;
 If X1<X3 Then
  Begin
   DirXT:=1;
   IncXT:=-IncXT;
  End;
 Inc(IncXT);
 CntXT:=IncXT ShR 1;

 IncYT:=Y3-Y1+1;
 CntYT:=IncYT ShR 1;

 LimT:=IncXT;
 If IncXT<IncYT Then
  LimT:=IncYT;

 (* Imposta i valori iniziali delle VAR. locali *)

 XT:=X1;
 OY2:=Y2;

 Finished:=True;
 F1:=(Y1>=Y2) Or (Y2<>Y3);
 F24:=((Y1<>Y2) Or (Y2>=Y3)) And
      ((Y1>=Y2) Or (Y2>=Y3));

 (* Disegna il primo vertice del triangolo *)

 If (X1=X2) And (X2=X3) And
    (Y1=Y2) And (Y2=Y3) Then
  Begin
   Segm.XY.X:=X1;
   Segm.XY.Y:=Y1;
   Segm.Dim_XY.DimX:=1;
   Col1:=BrdColAB;
   If Col1<0 Then
    Col1:=BrdColCA;
   If Col1<0 Then
    Col1:=FillColor;
   If Col1>=0 Then
   If Col1<256 Then
    PutHorizLine(@Segm,OBPVBuff,Col1,Clipp)
   Else
    PutShadowHorizLine(@Segm,OBPVBuff,ShadowTable,Clipp);
  End;

 (* Disegna il triangolo *)

 Repeat

  (* Calc. gli Incr. e i limiti, inizial. i cont. per il lato A-B (Bresenham) *)

  DirX1:=-1;
  IncX1:=X1-X2;
  If X1<X2 Then
   Begin
    DirX1:=1;
    IncX1:=-IncX1;
   End;
  Inc(IncX1);
  CntX1:=IncX1 ShR 1;

  IncY1:=Y2-Y1+1;
  CntY1:=IncY1 ShR 1;

  Lim1:=IncX1;
  If IncX1<IncY1 Then
   Lim1:=IncY1;

  FX1:=X1;
  FXT:=XT;
  Overflow:=False;

  (* Rappresenta un semi-triangolo *)

  While (X1<>X2) Or (Y1<>Y2) Do
   Begin

    (* Calcola i 4 estremi del SEGMENTO orizzontale da disegnare *)

    Repeat

     Internal:=Overflow;

     If Overflow Then
      Begin

       Dec(CntY1,Lim1);
       Dec(CntYT,LimT);

       Inc(Y1);

      End;

     Overflow:=True;

     Tmp:=CntY1+IncY1;

     If Tmp<Lim1 Then
      Begin

       CntY1:=Tmp;
       Inc(CntX1,IncX1);

       If CntX1>=Lim1 Then
        Begin
         Dec(CntX1,Lim1);
         Inc(X1,DirX1);
        End;

       Overflow:=False;

      End;

     Tmp:=CntYT+IncYT;

     If Tmp<LimT Then
      Begin

       CntYT:=Tmp;
       Inc(CntXT,IncXT);

       If CntXT>=LimT Then
        Begin
         Dec(CntXT,LimT);
         Inc(XT,DirXT);
        End;

       Overflow:=False;

      End;

     If Internal Then
      Begin
       FX1:=X1;
       FXT:=XT;
      End;

    Until Overflow;

    (* Ordina (ordine ascendente) i 4 estremi del SEGMENTO orizzontale *)

    B1L:=FX1;
    B1H:=X1;

    If B1L>B1H Then
     Begin
      Tmp:=B1L;
      B1L:=B1H;
      B1H:=Tmp;
     End;

    B2L:=FXT;
    B2H:=XT;

    If B2L>B2H Then
     Begin
      Tmp:=B2L;
      B2L:=B2H;
      B2H:=Tmp;
     End;

    Col1:=BrdColAB;
    Col2:=BrdColCA;

    If (B2L<B1L) Or (B2H<B1H) Then
     Begin
      Tmp:=B1L;
      B1L:=B2L;
      B2L:=Tmp;
      Tmp:=B1H;
      B1H:=B2H;
      B2H:=Tmp;
      Tmp:=Col1;
      Col1:=Col2;
      Col2:=Tmp;
     End;

    D1:=B1H-B1L+1;
    D0:=B2L-B1H-1;
    D2:=B2H-B2L+1;

    (* Ove possibile unisce i bordi con la parte centrale del Segm. orizz. *)

    If D0>0 Then
     Begin

      If FillColor=Col2 Then (* Parte0 unita a parte2, parte0 esistente *)
       Begin
        Inc(D0,D2);
        D2:=0;
       End;

      If Col1=FillColor Then (* Parte0 unita a parte1, parte0 esistente *)
       Begin
        B1H:=B1L-1;
        Inc(D0,D1);
        D1:=0;
       End;

     End
    Else
     Begin

      D0:=0;

      If Col1=Col2 Then (* Parte1 unita a parte2, parte0 inesistente *)
       Begin
        D1:=B2H-B1L+1;
        D2:=0;
       End;

     End;

    (* Rappresenta il primo bordo del Segm. orizz. *)

    Segm.XY.Y:=Y1;

    Segm.XY.X:=B1L;
    Segm.Dim_XY.DimX:=D1;
    If Col1>=0 Then
    If Col1<256 Then
     PutHorizLine(@Segm,OBPVBuff,Col1,Clipp)
    Else
     PutShadowHorizLine(@Segm,OBPVBuff,ShadowTable,Clipp);

    (* Rappresenta la parte centrale del Segm. orizz. *)

    If (Y1<>OY2) Or
       (Not Finished Or F1) And (Finished Or F24) Then
     Begin
      Segm.XY.X:=B1H+1;
      Segm.Dim_XY.DimX:=D0;
      If FillColor>=0 Then
      If FillColor<256 Then
       PutHorizLine(@Segm,OBPVBuff,FillColor,Clipp)
      Else
       PutShadowHorizLine(@Segm,OBPVBuff,ShadowTable,Clipp);
     End;

    (* Rappresenta il secondo bordo del Segm. orizz. *)

    Segm.XY.X:=B2L;
    Segm.Dim_XY.DimX:=D2;
    If Col2>=0 Then
    If Col2<256 Then
     PutHorizLine(@Segm,OBPVBuff,Col2,Clipp)
    Else
     PutShadowHorizLine(@Segm,OBPVBuff,ShadowTable,Clipp);

   End;

  X2:=X3;
  Y2:=Y3;

  BrdColAB:=BrdColBC;

  Finished:=Not Finished;

 Until Finished;

End;
```

Here it is the draw horizontal lines' routines:

```
Procedure PutHorizLine(Segm:T_Rect_Ptr;OBPVBuff:Pointer;
                       Color:Cardinal;
                       Clipp:T_Clipp_Rect_Ptr); Assembler;

Asm

     ClD                  {Direzione ascendente stringhe}

     Push  EBX            {Salva il REG. EBX sullo STACK}
     Push  EDI            {Salva il REG. EDI sullo STACK}
     Push  ESI            {Salva il REG. ESI sullo STACK}
     Push  EBP            {Salva il REG. EBP sullo STACK}

    {-----------------------------}

     Mov   ESI,Segm       {EAX}
     Mov   EDI,OBPVBuff   {EDX}
     Mov   EDX,Color      {ECX}
     Mov   EBP,Clipp

    {-----------------------------}

     Sub   ESP,5          {Alloca 2 VAR. locali sullo STACK}

    {[ESP+1]:              ClippY;
     [ESP]:                Color}

    {-----------------------------}

     Mov   [ESP],DL       {Salva Color}

    {-----------------------------}

     XOr   EAX,EAX        {Annulla EAX}

    {-----------------------------}

    {REG. EAX, EBX, ECX e EDX liberi}

     Cmp   EDI,EAX        {Se OBPVBuff = NIL ...}
     JE    @@00           {Allora Esce}

    {-----------------------------}

     Mov   EBX,EAX        {Annulla EBX}
     Mov   EDX,EAX        {Annulla EDX}

     Cmp   EBP,EAX        {Se Clipp=NIL ...}
     JE    @@01           {Allora Vai @@01}

     Mov   BX,[EBP]             {EBX <- ClippX}
     Mov   AX,[EBP+2]           {EAX <- ClippY}
     Mov   DX,[EBP+4]           {EDX <- ClippDimX}
     MovZX EBP,Word Ptr [EBP+6] {EBP <- ClippDimY}

    {-----------------------------}

@@01:Cmp   Word Ptr [EDI],0     {Se DimScrX<=0 ...}
     JLE   @@00                 {ha finito}

     Cmp   BX,0                 {Se ClippX<0 ...}
     JS    @@00                 {ha finito}

     Cmp   DX,0                 {Se ClippDimX<0 ...}
     JS    @@00                 {ha finito}
     JNE   @@02                 {Se ClippDimX=0 ...}

     Mov   DX,[EDI]             {allora ClippDimX <- DimScrX}

@@02:LEA   ECX,[EBX+EDX]        {Se ClippX+ClippDimX ...}
     Cmp   CX,[EDI]             {>DimScrX ...}
     JA    @@00                 {ha finito}

    {-----------------------------}

     Cmp   Word Ptr [EDI+2],0   {Se DimScrY<=0 ...}
     JLE   @@00                 {ha finito}

     Cmp   AX,0                 {Se ClippY<0 ...}
     JS    @@00                 {ha finito}

     Cmp   BP,0                 {Se ClippDimY<0 ...}
     JS    @@00                 {ha finito}
     JNE   @@03                 {Se ClippDimY=0 ...}

     Mov   BP,[EDI+2]           {allora ClippDimY <- DimScrY}

@@03:LEA   ECX,[EAX+EBP]        {Se ClippY+ClippDimY ...}
     Cmp   CX,[EDI+2]           {>DimScrY ...}
     JA    @@00                 {ha finito}

    {-----------------------------}

     Mov   [ESP+1],EAX          {Salva ClippY}

    {REG. EAX e ECX liberi}

    {-----------------------------}

     XOr   AX,AX          {Annulla EAX}
     Mov   ECX,EAX        {Annulla ECX}

     Cmp   ESI,EAX        {Se Segm=NIL ...}
     JE    @@04           {Allora Vai @@04}

     MovSX EAX,Word Ptr [ESI+2] {EAX <- Segm.XY.Y}
     Mov   CX,[ESI+4]           {ECX <- Segm.Dim_XY.DimX (DimX)}
     MovSX ESI,Word Ptr [ESI]   {ESI <- Segm.XY.X}

    {-----------------------------}

@@04:Cmp   AX,BP          {Se (Segm.XY.Y >= ClippDimY) O (Segm.XY.Y < 0) ...}
     JAE   @@00           {Allora Esce}

     Cmp   SI,DX          {Se Segm.XY.X >= ClippDimX ...}
     JGE   @@00           {Allora Esce}

     Or    CX,CX          {Se DimX <= 0 ...}
     JLE   @@00           {Allora Esce}

    {-----------------------------}

     Add   ECX,ESI        {INC (DimX, Segm.XY.X)}
     JLE   @@00           {Se DimX <= 0, Allora Esce}

     Or    SI,SI          {Se Segm.XY.X >= 0 ...}
     JNS   @@05           {Allora Vai @@05}

     XOr   ESI,ESI        {Segm.XY.X <- 0}

@@05:Cmp   CX,DX          {Se DimX <= ClippDimX ...}
     JBE   @@06           {Allora Vai @@06}

     Mov   CX,DX          {DimX <- ClippDimX}

@@06:Sub   ECX,ESI        {DEC (DimX, Segm.XY.X}
(*   JE    @@00           {Se DimX = 0, Allora Esce} *)

    {REG. EDX e EBP liberi}

    {-----------------------------}

     Mov   BP,[EDI]       {Calcola IN EBP la Dim. X di OBPVBuff^ ...}
     And   BP,R_OBP_Al-1
     Neg   BP
     Add   BP,R_OBP_Al
     And   BP,R_OBP_Al-1
     Add   BP,[EDI]       {allineata ai 16 BYTE (ADimX)}

    {-----------------------------}

     Add   EDI,EBX        {OBPVBuff + Clipp.XY.X}

    {-----------------------------}

     Add   EAX,[ESP+1]    {INC (Segm.XY.Y, Clipp.XY.Y)}

     Mul   EBP            {WAddr <- (Clipp.XY.Y + Segm.XY.Y) * ADimX}

     Add   EDI,EAX        {OBPVBuff + WAddr + ...}

     LEA   EDI,[EDI+ESI+DimOBP_H] {Segm.XY.X + DimOBP_H}

    {REG. EAX, EDX, ESI e EBX liberi}

    {-----------------------------}

     Mov   DL,[ESP]       {Ripristina Color dallo STACK}

     Mov   DH,DL          {Carica IN ogni BYTE di EAX ...}
     Mov   AX,DX
     ShL   EAX,16
     Mov   AX,DX          {il colore Color}

    {REG. EDX, ESI e EBX liberi}

    {-----------------------------}

     Mov   DL,CL          {DL <- Lo(DimX)}
     ShR   ECX,2          {ECX= DimX/4}
     Rep   StoSD          {Riempie ECX DoubleWord}
     SetB  CL             {ECX= resto di (DimX/2)/2}
     Rep   StoSW          {Riempie ECX WORD}
     Test  DL,1           {ECX= ...}
     SetNE CL             {resto di DimX/2}
     Rep   StoSB          {Riempie ECX BYTE}

    {-----------------------------}

@@00:Add   ESP,5          {Dealloca 2 VAR. locali dallo STACK}

    {-----------------------------}

     Pop   EBP            {Ripristina il REG. EBP dallo STACK}
     Pop   ESI            {Ripristina il REG. ESI dallo STACK}
     Pop   EDI            {Ripristina il REG. EDI dallo STACK}
     Pop   EBX            {Ripristina il REG. EBX dallo STACK}

End;
```

Here it is the representation of a transparent horizontal line:

```
Procedure PutShadowHorizLine(Segm:T_Rect_Ptr;OBPVBuff:Pointer;
                             ShadowTable:T_Shadow_Table_Ptr;
                             Clipp:T_Clipp_Rect_Ptr); Assembler;

Asm

     ClD                  {Direzione ascendente stringhe}

     Push  EBX            {Salva il REG. EBX sullo STACK}
     Push  EDI            {Salva il REG. EDI sullo STACK}
     Push  ESI            {Salva il REG. ESI sullo STACK}
     Push  EBP            {Salva il REG. EBP sullo STACK}

    {-----------------------------}

     Mov   ESI,Segm       {EAX}
     Mov   EDI,OBPVBuff   {EDX}
     Mov   EDX,ShadowTable{ECX}
     Mov   EBP,Clipp

    {-----------------------------}

     Sub   ESP,8          {Alloca 2 VAR. locali sullo STACK}

    {[ESP+4]:              ClippY;
     [ESP]:                ShadowTable}

    {-----------------------------}

     Mov   [ESP],EDX      {Salva ShadowTable}

    {-----------------------------}

     XOr   EAX,EAX        {Annulla EAX}

    {-----------------------------}

    {REG. EAX, EBX e ECX liberi}

     Cmp   EDI,EAX        {Se OBPVBuff = NIL ...}
     JE    @@00           {Allora Esce}

    {-----------------------------}

     Cmp   EDX,EAX        {Se ShadowTable = NIL ...}
     JE    @@00           {Allora Esce}

    {-----------------------------}

     Mov   EBX,EAX        {Annulla EBX}
     Mov   EDX,EAX        {Annulla EDX}

     Cmp   EBP,EAX        {Se Clipp=NIL ...}
     JE    @@01           {Allora Vai @@01}

     Mov   BX,[EBP]             {EBX <- ClippX}
     Mov   AX,[EBP+2]           {EAX <- ClippY}
     Mov   DX,[EBP+4]           {EDX <- ClippDimX}
     MovZX EBP,Word Ptr [EBP+6] {EBP <- ClippDimY}

    {-----------------------------}

@@01:Cmp   Word Ptr [EDI],0     {Se DimScrX<=0 ...}
     JLE   @@00                 {ha finito}

     Cmp   BX,0                 {Se ClippX<0 ...}
     JS    @@00                 {ha finito}

     Cmp   DX,0                 {Se ClippDimX<0 ...}
     JS    @@00                 {ha finito}
     JNE   @@02                 {Se ClippDimX=0 ...}

     Mov   DX,[EDI]             {allora ClippDimX <- DimScrX}

@@02:LEA   ECX,[EBX+EDX]        {Se ClippX+ClippDimX ...}
     Cmp   CX,[EDI]             {>DimScrX ...}
     JA    @@00                 {ha finito}

    {-----------------------------}

     Cmp   Word Ptr [EDI+2],0   {Se DimScrY<=0 ...}
     JLE   @@00                 {ha finito}

     Cmp   AX,0                 {Se ClippY<0 ...}
     JS    @@00                 {ha finito}

     Cmp   BP,0                 {Se ClippDimY<0 ...}
     JS    @@00                 {ha finito}
     JNE   @@03                 {Se ClippDimY=0 ...}

     Mov   BP,[EDI+2]           {allora ClippDimY <- DimScrY}

@@03:LEA   ECX,[EAX+EBP]        {Se ClippY+ClippDimY ...}
     Cmp   CX,[EDI+2]           {>DimScrY ...}
     JA    @@00                 {ha finito}

    {-----------------------------}

     Mov   [ESP+4],EAX          {Salva ClippY}

    {REG. EAX e ECX liberi}

    {-----------------------------}

     XOr   AX,AX          {Annulla EAX}
     Mov   ECX,EAX        {Annulla ECX}

     Cmp   ESI,EAX        {Se Segm=NIL ...}
     JE    @@04           {Allora Vai @@04}

     MovSX EAX,Word Ptr [ESI+2] {EAX <- Segm.XY.Y}
     Mov   CX,[ESI+4]           {ECX <- Segm.Dim_XY.DimX (DimX)}
     MovSX ESI,Word Ptr [ESI]   {ESI <- Segm.XY.X}

    {-----------------------------}

@@04:Cmp   AX,BP          {Se (Segm.XY.Y >= ClippDimY) O (Segm.XY.Y < 0) ...}
     JAE   @@00           {Allora Esce}

     Cmp   SI,DX          {Se Segm.XY.X >= ClippDimX ...}
     JGE   @@00           {Allora Esce}

     Or    CX,CX          {Se DimX <= 0 ...}
     JLE   @@00           {Allora Esce}

    {-----------------------------}

     Add   ECX,ESI        {INC (DimX, Segm.XY.X)}
     JLE   @@00           {Se DimX <= 0, Allora Esce}

     Or    SI,SI          {Se Segm.XY.X >= 0 ...}
     JNS   @@05           {Allora Vai @@05}

     XOr   ESI,ESI        {Segm.XY.X <- 0}

@@05:Cmp   CX,DX          {Se DimX <= ClippDimX ...}
     JBE   @@06           {Allora Vai @@06}

     Mov   CX,DX          {DimX <- ClippDimX}

@@06:Sub   ECX,ESI        {DEC (DimX, Segm.XY.X}
(*   JE    @@00           {Se DimX = 0, Allora Esce} *)

    {REG. EDX e EBP liberi}

    {-----------------------------}

     Mov   BP,[EDI]       {Calcola IN EBP la Dim. X di OBPVBuff^ ...}
     And   BP,R_OBP_Al-1
     Neg   BP
     Add   BP,R_OBP_Al
     And   BP,R_OBP_Al-1
     Add   BP,[EDI]       {allineata ai 16 BYTE (ADimX)}

    {-----------------------------}

     Add   EDI,EBX        {OBPVBuff + Clipp.XY.X}

    {-----------------------------}

     Add   EAX,[ESP+4]    {INC (Segm.XY.Y, Clipp.XY.Y)}

     Mul   EBP            {WAddr <- (Clipp.XY.Y + Segm.XY.Y) * ADimX}

     Add   EDI,EAX        {OBPVBuff + WAddr + ...}
     LEA   EDI,[EDI+ESI+DimOBP_H] {Segm.XY.X + DimOBP_H}

    {REG. EAX, EDX, ESI e EBX liberi}

    {-----------------------------}

     Mov   EDX,[ESP]      {Ripristina ShadowTable dallo STACK}
     XOr   EAX,EAX        {EAX <- 0}

    {REG. ESI e EBX liberi}

    {-----------------------------}

@@07:Mov   AL,[EDI]       {[WAddr] <- ...}
     Mov   AL,[EDX+EAX]   {ShadowTable^ ...}
     StoSB                {[[WAddr]]; INC (WAddr)}

     Loop  @@07           {Se DimY <> 0, Allora Ripete Ciclo}

    {-----------------------------}

@@00:Add   ESP,8          {Dealloca 2 VAR. locali dallo STACK}

    {-----------------------------}

     Pop   EBP            {Ripristina il REG. EBP dallo STACK}
     Pop   ESI            {Ripristina il REG. ESI dallo STACK}
     Pop   EDI            {Ripristina il REG. EDI dallo STACK}
     Pop   EBX            {Ripristina il REG. EBX dallo STACK}

End;
```

Represents a triangle A (X1, Y1) -B (X2, Y2) -C (X3, Y3), full or empty, with border, solid or transparent, on the BUFFER VIDEO in OBP format.

FillColor: Interior color of the triangle:

```
    -1= No filling;
0..255= Solid FillColor color filler;
   256= Transparent fill (use `ShadowTable^`).
```

BrdColAB: Color of the A-B side of the triangle:

```
    -1= No border;
0..255= Solid `BrdColAB` border color of side A-B;
   256= Transparent border (use `ShadowTable^`).
```

BrdColBC: Color of the B-C side of the triangle:

```
    -1= No border;
0..255= Solid `BrdColBC` border color of side B-C;
   256= Transparent border (use `ShadowTable^`).
```

BrdColCA: Color of the C-A side of the triangle:

```
    -1= No border;
0..255= Solid `BrdColCA` border color of side C-A;
   256= Transparent border (use `ShadowTable^`).
```

You must specify `BrdColAB` =`BrdColBC`, `BrdColAB` =`BrdColCA` and `BrdColAB` <>`FillColor` to represent an bordered triangle.

You must specify `BrdColAB`=`BrdColBC`, `BrdColAB`=`BrdColCA`, `BrdColAB`=`FillColor` to represent an full triangle.

`OBPVBuff` must be correctly allocated and contains the video buffer in "OBP" format for the screen.

The "OBP" format ("One Byte, one Pixel") it's my image format 8 Bit / Pixel.

The first 2 words contain the image oriented from left to right (X +) and from top to bottom (Y +).
This image has the lines aligned to the 16 Bytes, so the final part of them can contain zeros, when dimension X is not a multiple of 16, since the origin is `(OBPVBuff + 16) ^`.
I created an allocation function of the memory in mode of OBPVBuff returns always aligned with 16 Bytes.

ADDRESS OUTPUT TO `(OBPVBuff + 16) ^`.

The clipping-region specified by `Clipp`, must always have an origin with positive coordinates, but the dimensions of it can exceed that the video buffer. They are not allowed negative dimensions of the clipping region (in any case incorrect values are tolerated for clipping-region).

The COORDINATES `X`n and`Y`n of the vertices of the triangle they can be any.

This function uses my own implementation of the generic `Bresenham` algorithm.

Comment: Is this really a relevant answer to the question?

Comment: I agree with you. I have not found any question that it was relevant with my answer. Maybe my approach to this site is wrong. Could you please tell me if someone has requested a function, even in C, to quickly draw any type of triangle (... you took 2 points from me)? My answer is here: but I could remove it and reinsert it in a suitable way, which is more correct. Unfortunately, I don't have much time.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. StackOverflow is very strict about the Q and A format. Each A must be an *answer* to the Q (it mustn't be a comment, a reply to another answer, or a text not exactly answering the Q), and it is often emphasised that StackOverflow isn't a "forum". Maybe you have a blog that you can post your code on?

Comment: If you want to learn more about how StackOverflow works, you can read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).